# Case expressions must be constant

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error
Case expressions must be constant
When I try to use value of the map in switch case

Don't know how to fix it

```
const map = {'cat': 10, 'dog': 7, 'mouse': 4};


function(animal) {
  switch(animal){
    case map['cat'] {
      print('ok');
    }
    case map['dog']{
      print('not ok');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can not use dynamic value after case keyword it requires a const value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using switch and case you cant use values which are known only at run time after the "case" keyword

if you want to check if an animal is a dog or cat, and animal is supposed to be a string type, try writing:

```
function(animal) {
  switch(animal){
    case 'cat':
      print('ok');
      break;

    case 'dog':
      print('not ok');
      break;
  }
}
```